# Can I add new fields to existing document if I know its title field value and not the id?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I create city documents where I save some fields like title and description. Is it possible to add some fields later to a specific city b y knowing the city title for that db.collection path instead of the id?

First elements added

```
public createSavedCity(title: string, desc: string): void {

const cityFields = {
  title: title,
  description: desc
}



this.db.collection('saved').add(savedFields);}
```

I will use a new function to update the document which will receive as a parameter the title of the document I want to update

```
updateDoc(savedTitle: string, newItem: string) : void {

  this.db.collection.(`saved/${savedTitle}`).update({newField: newItem});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can [query](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md#4-querying-collections-in-angularfirestore) for documents using that title, iterate the results, and use the [update()](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#manipulating-documents) method to change the contents of an existing document using DocumentReference.

Comment: I can pass the title of a city as a parameter to the function that will update the current document. In this function how should the path look? Will this path be correct? this.db.collection.(`saved/${savedTitle}`).update();

Comment: That will not work.  The only way you can build a document reference is if you know the ID of the document.  You can't use a value of a property in that document.  You will first have to query for the document in order to find its reference, then update it.

Comment: So I need to query the collection to find the city with that title, and then pass that city id to my function in order to update this city fields

Comment: Yes, or you can use the document reference available from the query snapshot instead of building a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance