# Not able to add a new field to an existing document in firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a new field(reactions) to an existing document using `updateDoc` method but it's not adding a new field.
This is how I'm doing:

```
      const newUserReactions = [...reactions, newReaction]
      console.log(newUserReactions)
      updateDocument(docID, { reactions: newUserReactions })
```

`reactions` field doesn't exist on the document

updateDocument:

```
const updateDocument = async (id, updates) => {
    dispatch({ type: "IS_PENDING" })
    try {
      const updatedDocument = await updateDoc(doc(db, c, id), updates)
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "UPDATED_DOCUMENT", payload: updatedDocument })
      return updatedDocument
    } catch (error) {
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "ERROR", payload: error })
      return null
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is the `c` in your path? Because syntax is correct.

Comment: c is the collection name that I pass like this:   `const { updateDocument } = useFirestore("solutions")`

Comment: Basically, I call useFirestore hook to get the updateDocument function

Comment: @r007,Please let me know if the answer was helpful or any further information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to write data to Cloud Firestore:

- Set the data of a document within a collection, explicitly specifying
  a document identifier.
- Add a new document to a collection. In this    case, Cloud Firestore
  automatically generates the document    identifier.
- Create an empty document with an automatically    generated
  identifier, and assign data to it later.

When you are trying to update a document in Cloud Firestore requires knowing its ID. To update some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document, use the `update()` method:
You can do the updates by following the below algorithmic logic.
1.Run a query with your conditions to determine the document ID.
2.Update the documents with individual updates, or with one or more batched writes[1]

```
const docRef = db.collection('objects').doc('some-id');
 
// Update the timestamp field with the value from the server
const res = await docRef.update({
  timestamp: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});
```

Note that you only need the document ID from step 1. So you could run a query that only returns the IDs. This is not possible in the client-side SDKs, but can be done through the REST API and Admin SDKs as shown here [2]

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp
[2] : [How to get a list of document IDs in a collection Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061903/how-to-get-a-list-of-keys-in-firestore)

Are there any specific errors other than the one specified ? Also, please share the pre and the post screen-shot of the Firestore Data from Firebase console.
You may refer the following links for further reference:

[3] : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document
[4] : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document
[5] : https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-set-field#firestore_data_set_field-nodejs
[6] : [Can I add new fields to existing document if I know its title field value and not the id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58733540/can-i-add-new-fields-to-existing-document-if-i-know-its-title-field-value-and-no)